# Enlisting a Cosmos transaction in a Sql Server Database Transaction

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We are using Entity Framework Core 3 and Cosmos 3.4 with Sql API.

Is it possible to enlist a Cosmos (Microsoft DocumentDb) transaction in a Sql Server Transaction so that the RollBack/Commit applies to Both Sql Server and the Cosmos.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos DB has no transactional support outside of Cosmos DB itself. Its transactions are either at the *document* level (e.g. inserting a document) or at a *stored procedure* level (e.g. modifying several documents within the stored procedure, which takes place within a single partition of a single collection).

There's no way to have actual transactional commit/rollback connected with SQL Server (or any other database) outside of Cosmos DB. You'd need come up with your own strategy for keeping data in sync between the two databases.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my problem. Any idea about a solution?