# Transactions at container level in Cosmos Db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a transaction which updates documents in two different containers. How can I maintain transaction in this case in cosmos Db

Comment: To add to Guarav's answer: While you can perform transactional updates to multiple documents using either stored procedures or the transactional batch feature all the participating documents has to both reside in the same container as well as share the same partition key. The scalability of Cosmos can only be fulfilled with limitations like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle Transaction in CosmosDB - "All or nothing" concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447997/how-to-handle-transaction-in-cosmosdb-all-or-nothing-concept)

Comment: Also please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58895394/272109) from a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is that you can't. Documents and all operations on them are scoped to a container and cross-container operations are not supported.

Comment: Slight refinement: Scoped to a *partition* within a container.